# How to get number of arguments in a constructor

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In my .net windows application(c#) i want know the number of arguments in each constructor of a particular class. I get all the constructor by using reflection. Is it possible to get the `number of arguments of each constructors`?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ask for its parameters (through [GetParameters()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getparameters.aspx)), then ask for the length of the array.

```
ConstructorInfo ctor = /* ... */
int numberOfArguments = ctor.GetParameters().Length;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Type t = typeof(...);

var constructors = t.GetConstructors();
foreach (var con in constructors)
{
    Console.WriteLine(con.GetParameters().Length);
}
```